# Specification of Extended Properties in OleDb connection string?

Tags: c#, ado.net, connection, connection-string

At the moment I'm searching for properties for a connection string, which can be used to connect to an Excel file in readonly mode. Searching Google gets me a lot of examples of connection strings, but I can't seem to find a specification of all possibilities in the 'Extended Properties' section of the OleDb connection string.

At the moment I've this:

```
Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = D:\Data\Customers.xls; Extended Properties = 'Excel 8.0; Mode=Read; ReadOnly=true; HDR=Yes';
```

However... I've composed this by examples. So questions:
1. What is a decent source for OleDb Connection String documentation/reference?
2. Is the above connection string indeed connecting to the Excel file in readonly mode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using UDL file for that.

Do next:

> 1. create empty file test.udl
> 2. open it
> 3. You will see Data Link Properties dialog
> 4. On first tab change provider to Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
> 5. Second tab select you Excel file
> 6. Third tab set permission like Read
> 7. On last tab set Extended Properties = 'Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes'

Than save, and open file in text editor and you will see connection string

As well you can check msdn article [ADO Provider Properties and Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140022(office.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

COM-based data access to Excel specifications are likely buried in nearly inaccessible Microsoft archive documentation. (Usually served as one enormous PDF)

I added the spec to another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68912543/6237912

Copied to this answer for completeness:

> The connectionstring has some parts:
>
> Provider: It is the main oledb provider that is used to open the Excel
> sheet. This will be Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 for Excel 97 onwards Excel
> file format and Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 for Excel 2007 or higher
> Excel file format (One with xlsx extension)
>
> Data Source: It is the entire path of the Excel workbook. You need to mention a dospath that corresponds to an Excel file. Thus, it will
> look like: Data Source=C:\testApp.xls".
>
> Extended Properties (Optional): Extended properties can be applied to Excel workbooks which may change the overall activity of the Excel
> workbook from your program. The most common ones are the following:
>
> HDR: It represents Header of the fields in the Excel table. Default is YES. If you don't have fieldnames in the header of your
> worksheet, you can specify HDR=NO which will take the columns of the
> tables that it finds as f1,f2 etc.
>
> ReadOnly: You can also open Excel workbook in readonly mode by specifying ReadOnly=true; By default, Readonly attribute is false, so
> you can modify data within your workbook.
>
> FirstRowHasNames: It is the same as HDR, it is always set to 1 ( which means true) you can specify it as false if you don't have your
> header row. If HDR is YES, provider disregards this property. You can
> change the default behaviour of your environment by changing the
> Registry Value
> [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel\FirstRowHasNames] to 00
> (which is false)
>
> MaxScanRows: Excel does not provide the detailed schema defination of the tables it finds. It need to scan the rows before
> deciding the data types of the fields. MaxScanRows specifies the
> number of cells to be scanned before deciding the data type of the
> column. By default, the value of this is 8. You can specify any value
> from 1 - 16 for 1 to 16 rows. You can also make the value to 0 so that
> it searches all existing rows before deciding the data type. You can
> change the default behaviour of this property by changing the value of
> [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows] which is
> 8 by default. Currently, MaxScanRows is ignored, so you need only to
> depend on TypeGuessRows Registry value. Hope Microsoft fixes this
> issue to its later versions.
>
> IMEX: (A Caution) As mentioned above, Excel will have to guess a number or rows to select the most appropriate data type of the
> column, a serious problem may occur if you have mixed data in one
> column. Say you have data of both integer and text on a single column,
> in that case, Excel will choose its data type based on majority of the
> data. Thus it selects the data for the majority data type that is
> selected, and returns NULL for the minority data type. If the two
> types are equally mixed in the column, the provider chooses numeric
> over text.
>
> For example, in your eight (8) scanned rows, if the column contains five (5) numeric values and three (3) text values, the
> provider returns five (5) numbers and three (3) null values.
>
> To work around this problem for data, set "IMEX=1" in the Extended Properties section of the connection string. This enforces
> the ImportMixedTypes=Text registry setting. You can change the
> enforcement of type by changing
> [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel\ImportMixedTypes] to
> numeric as well.
>
> Thus if you look into the simple connectionstring with all of them, it will look like:
>
> ```
>     Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\\testexcel.xls;
>     Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;MAXSCANROWS=15;READONLY=FALSE\""
>
>     or:
>     Copy Code
>
>     Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\testexcel.xlsx;
>     Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;MAXSCANROWS=15;READONLY=FALSE\""
> ```
>
> We need to place extended properties into Quotes(") as there are multiple number of values.