# WHERE clause IN array for mixed data types gives Error: Data type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

The array I have is filled with both integer and string, same as the source file. As such, the macro I came up with failed to capture the data I queried.

```
Sub QueryID()
Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim qName As String
    Dim connString As String, sSql As String, Filepath As String, sourceshname As String
    Dim targetsh As Worksheet
    Dim mainws As Worksheet

' Assign filepath and source sheetname
    qName = "PowerQueryData"
    Filepath = Sheets("Sheet9").Range("C18").Value
    sourceshname = "Sheet1"

 ' Assign lookup range to an array
    Dim myRangeGG As Range
    Dim cell As Variant, myArr As Variant, resultID As Variant
    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    
    With mainws
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set myRangeGG = .Range("A2:A" & Lastrow)
    End With
    
    myArr = myRangeGG
    
    ' For checking of Array values only (debug)
    For Each cell In myArr
        Debug.Print cell
    Next cell
    
    For i = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
        For j = LBound(myArr, 2) To UBound(myArr, 2)
        If Not IsNumeric(myArr(i, j)) Then
            ' Concatenate each element with double quotes
            resultID = resultID & """" & myArr(i, j) & """"
        Else
            resultID = resultID & myArr(i, j)
        End If
        ' Add a comma if it's not the last element
            If i < UBound(myArr) Then
                resultID = resultID & ", "
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print resultID

    If Filepath <> "" And Filepath2 <> "" Then
        sSql = "SELECT * FROM [" & sourceshname & "$] WHERE [ID no#] IN (" & resultID & ")"
        Debug.Print sSql
        connString = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Filepath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"""
        Set qt = targetsh.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connString, Destination:=targetsh.Range("A2"), Sql:=sSql)
        With qt
            .Name = qName
            .FieldNames = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            .MaintainConnection = False
            .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Debug.Print shows the proper syntax used for integer and string in SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [ID no#] IN (5323214, 4332254, 7097427, 4152905, "A1894185", "A1894186", "A1894187", "A1894188")
```

The execution of this macro gives an error: Run-time error '1004': Data type mismatch in criteria expression. Is there a way to query a column containing mixed data type?

Comment: Have you tried adding IMEX=1 in the connection string?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735415/specification-of-extended-properties-in-oledb-connection-string

Answer (score 0):

Pass all values as text:

```vb
        For j = LBound(myArr, 2) To UBound(myArr, 2)
            ' Concatenate each element with double quotes
            resultID = resultID & """" & myArr(i, j) & """"
            ' Add a comma if it's not the last element
            ' <snip>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried with this earlier and it worked until the source data comes with more numeric values than text/string in that column - hence Excel 'guessed' the data type as numeric. Even though I manually formatted all values in the column to text, it didn't work.